# problem in action script3 function prevFrame

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i made a button  if you rollover on it it's size is larger
i want if you roll out on it it's size return back to it's original size
i use this function prevFrame 
but my problem is  when i use it 
it stops on the previous frame only
and i want to stop from the starting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can label your frames an use the gotoAndStop() method

```
function onRollover(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   gotoAndStop('largeSize');
}

function onRollOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   gotoAndStop('normalSize');
}
```

Comment: hi PatrickS thanks for your answer i want it for a game , so i want it to be frame by frame

Comment: ok, but there's only two frames in your button. Doesn't your button has its own movie clip?

Comment: yes but the butoon is Movie Clip n't a Button called btn_mc that's what i mean